# PHP file upload - Best security option for file types?

Tags: php, security, file-upload

The user needs to be allowed to upload almost any file type, but obviously I don't want anything malicious to be uploaded.  The upload form needs to allow things like .js and .php scripts, for example, though.

A whitelist could be endless, a blacklist might prevent legitimate files from being uploaded, and I'm not sure how much (if any) actual security those options even provide.

I am using CakePHP with its front controller, so you can't access the uploaded files directly through your browser.  The files are uploaded as `-rw-r--r--`.

What is my best option?  How protected is the server?

Comment: You should only care about viruses, if any. Just don't allow to **execute** the uploaded files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what *"gets routed through CakePHP and then serves the file to you"* means but, given the question, I have the impression that uploaded files get dropped to a public directory under `webroot` with their original extension intact and they're processed by the web server just like any other file you upload via FTP.

If that's the case, you have a bulging security issue out there and you need to fix the root problem rather than trying to paliate its effect with a weak workaround.

When dealing with user uploaded files you need to ensure that they're always handled as data, not as scripts. You could create a special directory where all its files are handled as data, no matter the file extension, though you'd need to tweak the web server configuration and you'd have to expect that nothing breaks in the future. Or, even better, put your upload directory **outside** the document root (or at least in a location that's not reachable by the web server) and write a PHP wrapper that reads the file and serves it as-is (i.e., a download script).

Comment: Yes, you are correct (I just meant that you cannot access the `webroot/files/...` directory directly from your browser). So if I upload to outside the document root, do I need to worry about what is uploaded if the files are not executable?  Anything else I need to consider?

Comment: If you don't execute them, you don't need to worry even if the files *are* executable.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to upload the data directly into the database as a BLOB, instead of allowing the user to upload to the filesystem.

Filesystems are complex and allowing users to upload directly to them introduces a large number of potential security holes; for example if someone uploads a file with the name "foo.php\0.jpg" (where \0 is byte value zero, the nul character), then your PHP will probably note that the string ends with the text ".jpg" and is thus "safe".

But when the string "foo.php\0.jpg" enters the fopen *underneath* PHP, it will be treated as a null-terminated string "foo.php", effectively allowing your user to upload arbitrary PHP to your website.

Similarly, it's difficult to stop malicious users uploading to /dev/hd0/ or to htt*://1.2.3.4/ or to \?\WEBDAV\1.2.3.4\ or to CON.txt or any such other nasty filesystem edge case that you almost certainly haven't thought about.

In order to be safe, the best way is to make sure that user data only gets stored in your DATAbase (that's why they call it that). Make additionally sure to parametrize your SQL and then you'll be reasonably safe from hostile attack.

You can always use PHP scripts to pull the data back out of the database later for serving back to other visitors, so doing so massively improves security with almost no major drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check on a list of extensions (don't use explode to check on extensions use pathinfo() instead).
2. Also check on the mimetype of the file.
3. Use a whitelist in stead of a blacklist even if it's extremely large it's always the safer solution.

Comment: The problem with the whitelist is that it could include almost any file in existence.  Is a list like that even available? Then there is the added problem of maintaining that list indefinitely.

Comment: True but don't you get the same problem with a blacklist? There are a lot of extensions that could harm the webserver like: php, cs, asp, exe etc. depending on what server you use of course.

Comment: @DillenMeijboom not really. .cs is a source file which will do nothing, .exe will not run on linux machines and .asp will only run if you have the framework installed.

Comment: Okay but what about ruby, python, C++ etc.?

Comment: I didn't say a blacklist is a good idea either.  I think both are a poor solution here.

Comment: Indeed, most of the times you only support one group of extensions for instance images (jpg, gif, tiff, png etc.) or media (mp3, wav) or movies (mp4, avi, divx etc.). I still think a whitelist is a better solution then a blacklist.